# Turbolinks remote link missing progress bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I have the following link in my Ruby on Rails 5 app:

```
  = link_to duplicate_slide_group_path(@survey, group), method: :post, remote: true, class: 'narrow button gray tooltip-attached duplicate-link', title: t('duplicate_group_and_contents_without_metadata') do
    = fa_icon 'file-o'
```

problem with that link is that when I click it, Turbolinks do not show progress bar, in non remote links progress bar is showing. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use in .js

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load',function(){

}
```

some thing like this